# Phalcon - How do i get the Url Query String with Dynamic Parameters into Volt to create pagination

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pagination, phalcon

I have follwoing query string generated by a "search form"

```
results?pagefrom=18&pageto=30&country=2&state=&city=0&keyword=&status=all&cmd=basic_search&Submit=Start+Searching
```

I need to know how do i get this into the pagination generation in volt like below

```
<li class="previous"><a href="/search/results?page={{ page.before }} & NEEDS TO ADD ABOVE QUERY AS IT IS HERE TO WORK ">Previous</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using something like this:

```
<li class="previous"><a href="/search/results?<?php echo http_build_query(array_merge($this->request->getQuery(), ['page' => $page->before])); ?>">Previous</a></li>
```

For more convenience, create marco:

```
{%- macro pagination_url(url, page) %}
    {{ url }}?<?php echo http_build_query(array_merge($this->request->getQuery(), ['page' => $page->before])); ?>
{% endmacro %}

<li class="previous"><a href="{{ pagination_url('/search/results', page.before) }}">Previous</a></li>
```

Or you can add this function to volt compiler:

```
$compiler = $volt->getCompiler();

$compiler->addFunction('pagination_url', function ($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) use ($compiler) {

     $url = $compiler->expression($exprArgs[0]['expr']);
     $page = $compiler->expression($exprArgs[1]['expr']);

     return $url . '.\'?\'.http_build_query(array_merge($this->request->getQuery(), [\'page\' => ' . $page . ']))';
});
```